# TDE using EKM device

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transparent-data-encryption

We use an external HSM device to create and store keys and use it for TDE.
Our auditors are asking questions about where the keys are store.  So obviously the key is stored in the external HSM device.

In this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/enable-tde-on-sql-server-using-ekm?view=sql-server-2014), under step 5,

```
USE master ;  
GO  
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY ekm_login_key   
FROM PROVIDER [EKM_Prov]  
WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_512,  
PROVIDER_KEY_NAME = 'SQL_Server_Key' ;  
GO
```

- **Does this create a copy of the key in master DB also?**
- **In case of TDE, how often does SQL Server has to contact the EKM device?  Does it have to contact the ekm device veytime while reading
  data file from disk?**

Answer (score 2):

> Does this create a copy of the key in master DB also?

Not according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/enable-tde-on-sql-server-using-ekm?view=sql-server-2017%20documentation). The asymmetric key is stored in your EKM device. There is a 'pointer' record in sys.asymmetric_keys which provides the information for retrieving the key from the EKM, but this requires credentials and permissions to access.

> In case of TDE, how often does SQL Server has to contact the EKM device? Does it have to contact the ekm device veytime while reading data file from disk?

The Asymmetric key created in your EKM device is used to protect the database encryption key which is stored in the boot page of the database. When the DB starts, the DEK is decrypted using the asymmetric key or certificate it was protected with, in your case the EKM's asymmetric key.

The DEK is used to encrypt/decrypt the data on disk, so the EKM should be contacted only once on startup of the database to decrypt the DEK.

Once decrypted, SQL Server can use the DEK to decrypt data when reading from disk without having to hit the EKM again.

See [Encryption Hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encryption-hierarchy?view=sql-server-2017%20Encryption%20Hierarchy) for more information

Comment: What if you have ... say 3000 databases, and they are all encrypted with the same credential? Since each database key would have to be decrypted by the EKM, I would think that it has to run 3,000 decryptions. Or does SQL server actually get the key so it can decrypt each DEK? Or can a SQL asymmetrical key by encrypted by the EKM, and then each DEK be encrypted by the same key on the server itself?

Comment: I'll answer my own comment. SQL has to decrypt 3000 DEKs, so it sends them to the HSM. SQL queues 50 at a time, which equates to around 0.5Mbps of traffic going to the HSM provider. It does add a few minutes to the overall database startup time, however, if a database is requested to be opened, it will move that to the top of the list with the batch of 50, so it will only take a few seconds to open depending on how fast your HSM can decrypt.  I find the EKM methodology to be a bit disappointing, because it would be just fine to allow the option of one single key, like a certificate allows.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this create a copy of the key in master DB also?

AFAIK, no.

> In case of TDE, how often does SQL Server has to contact the EKM device? Does it have to contact the ekm device veytime while reading data file from disk?

This depends on the HSM, the driver they provide which you need to have installed and loaded into the SQL Server process space but generally it will be cached for an undetermined period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Does this create a copy of the key in master DB also?

It doesn't create a copy of Key , but it's mapped the key from HSM to Master database, so that you can create a login with that asymmetric key to connect with HSM appliance with the help of credential

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/195693)